# how to store form validation errors in an array

Tags: php

If I have some basic form validations, (just using empty() for simplicities sake) and want to put those error messages into an array, how would I achieve this?

```
 $errors = array();
 $response = array();

if(empty($_POST['name'])) {

    $errors['name'] = "Name required";
}

if(empty($_POST['email'])) {

    $errors['email'] = "Email required";
}

$response['errors'] = $errors;

if(!empty($errors)) {

    $response['success'] = false;
    $response['message'] = "fail";

} else {

    $response['success'] = true;
    $response['message'] = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Success</div>";
}

echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: Just use an array instead of a string: `message[] = "..."`

Comment: I see you're using bootstrap. Are you using a PHP framework?

Comment: Yes, I am using bootstrap

Comment: Just like Marvin said, use $message[] or $message = array(). then just iterate.

Comment: I actually need to update my code because I want to use json. But I still need to get the errors into an array. Please see new code

Answer (score 1):

```
    $message = [];

if(empty($_POST['name'])) {

array_push($message , "Name required <br />");

}

if(empty($_POST['email'])) {

array_push($message , "Email required <br />");

}

if(!empty($message)) {
foreach ( $message as $str)
echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>" . $str . "</div>";

} else {
// success 

}
```

Comment: Apologies, I changed the code in the initial question